# Writing loops for interactive IO: problems with do-notation and layout

Tags: loops, haskell, io

I just started Haskell and it completely confuses me. I did Java and Python before which made a lot more sense to me.

I'm currently trying to get a user input, check if it is valid, if not: print an error and get the input again; if valid: produce a a boolean value from it.

To be more precise, I want a yes/no input, where 'y' will produce True, 'n' will produce False, and any other input will print a message into the command line and ask to input y/n again.

E.g.:

```
Continue? y/n:
> assd
Invalid input.
Continue? y/n:
> y
(something happens)
Continue? y/n:
> n
(Close program)
```

Writing it in farmiliar format, a function like this:

```
boolean inputBool() {
    while(True) {
       str = input("Continue? y/n: ");
       if (str == "y") {
           return True;
       } else if (str == "n") {
           return False;
       } else {
           print("Invalid input");
       }
}

--main program--

while(inputBool()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Since I just started haskell (today actually), I don't have much of an idea what I can or can't do.
I was thinking of something similar to:

```
yesno :: Bool
yesno = do
        putStr "Continue? y/n: " 
        str <- readLn
        if (str == "y") then True else (
            if (str == "n") then False else (
                do
                putStrLn "Invalid input."
                yesno
            )    
        )
```

Which doesn't work for many reasons. My main problem is that I don't know what this "do" does. I just read it's used when needing io operations and somehow executes the following expressions. Which doesn't make sense to me after reading that in haskell everything evaluates to a value. What does "do" evaluate to?
Also, what indentation is expected? It seems to be kind of random.
I know that the function has to evaluate to my boolean value, which doesn't seem to be possible with using this "do" operation. But then how do I print something to the console and still make it part of an expression that evaluates to True or False?

Thanks for any help.

(Btw. are there any active haskell forums on the internet? I couldn't find any =/)

Comment: Perhaps start with a good tutorial: http://learnyouahaskell.com/ or http://book.realworldhaskell.org/

Comment: The best forum for Haskell discussions are the Haskell Reddit, the Haskell Stackoverflow tag; the #haskell IRC channel; or the haskell-cafe@ mailing list.

Comment: Actually I'm really fed up with tutorials and those long explanations of everything. Ever since I started programming all I ever needed was syntax, keywords, a good documentation and a bit of practice.With this Java was learned in a matter of days and python was easy since I already knew java.

Comment: Haskell is wholly different though I and I didn't have any luck looking for a pure description of syntax & keywords. The documentation also seems pretty bad..

Comment: syntax and keywords won't help you, if the *semantics* of the language is different to what you already know -- as is the case with Haskell. You will need a good tutorial. http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world

Comment: Actually for you I would recommend haskell-beginners@haskell.org instead of haskell-cafe@haskell.org, which Don mentioned above.

Answer (score 21):

Since your function needs to perform IO, it must return a value in the `IO` monad, so its type needs to be `yesno :: IO Bool`, and the `True` and `False` values need to be lifted into the monad by `return`.  You also need `getLine` instead of `readLn`, since you want a raw string, and not a parsed value (which comes with the potential for a parse error).  Finally, you need to `hFlush stdout` before calling `getLine`, otherwise the prompt will still be sitting in the buffer waiting for a newline (and this requires that you import System.IO).

I've made the prompt string into an argument, so you can use the function to ask all sorts of yes/no questions:

```
import System.IO

yesno :: String -> IO Bool
yesno prompt = do
          putStr $ prompt ++ " y/n: "
          hFlush stdout
          str <- getLine
          case str of
            "y" -> return True
            "n" -> return False
            _   -> do
              putStrLn "Invalid input."
              yesno prompt
```

Then, you can call your function from an interaction loop:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
         fun <- yesno "Is Haskell fun?"
         if fun
          then putStrLn "rock on"
          else putStrLn "read more tutorials"
         continue <- yesno "Continue?"
         if continue then main else return ()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand this - so 'do' evaluates to its last expression?

Comment: Basically. A "do" block will evaluate to the value produced by a `return` -- depending on the execution path.

Comment: Yes, do is 'syntactic sugar', which glues a sequence of expressions acting as statements into one big expression.  The glue operator is (>>=) aka `bind`.

Comment: @Maro Assuming there is no error or fail or other "early exit" that happens before it gets there, yes.

Comment: You have to watch out for `return`.  It is not the same as return in Java or Python.  In Haskell, `return` wraps a value in a monadic shell, yielding a monadic value.  It does not cause the `do` block to stop executing.  Typically, you will see `return` as a leaf expression in the `do` block, so it will be the value returned from the block.

Comment: Since the expressions in a `do` block are glued together by the monad's `>>=` operator, it is the `>>=` operator that determines the value of the `do` block.  In the case of the `Maybe` monad, `Nothing >>= x` evaluates to `Nothing` without evaluating `x`, so any `return` in `x` is insignificant.

Comment: Updated the example to `hFlush stdout` so that it works when stdout is buffered.

Comment: Will `yesno` be tail-recursive? It seems that it can be, but will it, even without optimization? Otherwise it seems you'll overflow your stack.

Comment: @RobinGreen in `IO`, there's no "early exit" except for throwing exceptions, but there are other monads and monad transformers that provide the capability of early exit.

Comment: I understand that if I need to have some IO actions within a function I need to replace `myfunc :: String -> Int` by `myfunc :: String -> IO Int`, ex: `myfunc string = do putStr string` `strIO <- getLine` `return read strIO :: Int`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes and no.  You could for instance return a pure list of `IO` actions which the caller could `sequence`.  Incidentally, in your example, you would need parentheses around, or a `$` before the `read strIO` (otherwise you are applying `return ` to 2 arguments.  Also, the type annotation on the `read ` is redundant, since the type can be inferred from the type of `myfunc`.